# Адрес переменной ссылочного типа в памяти

Tags: c#, память

Выдаёт ошибку, что нельзя получить адрес памяти переменной управляемого типа, если я пытаюсь сделать так `&varString`.

Как возможно получить адрес памяти `string` и `char[]` и вывести его на экран? С числовыми всё понятно и символьными тоже.
Рабочий код:

```
int varInt = 123456;
string varString = "DefaultString"; 
string str = "Long char array right there ->";
const int size = 128;
char[] arrChar = new char[size];
arrChar = str.ToCharArray(); 

int* ptr2int = &varInt;
ulong addrInt = (ulong)ptr2int;

Console.WriteLine("varInt         " + "(0x" + addrInt.ToString("X") + ") = " + varInt);
Console.WriteLine("varString      " + "(string) = " + varString );
Console.Write("arrChar[128]   " + "(char[]) = ");

for (int i = 0; i < arrChar.Length; i++) Console.Write(arrChar[i]);
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо, чтобы вместо `string` и `char[]` был адрес памяти.
Насколько я понял надо взять первый символ в string и первый элемент char[]?

**Всё это нужно мне для чтения текста в string и char[]. Прочитать int я смог.*

Comment: `для чтения текста в string и char[]` - `var myString = new string(myCharArray);`?

Comment: `char[] arrChar = new char[size];` - здесь вы создали массив. `arrChar = str.ToCharArray();` - здесь вы его потеряли. / Рано вам в указатели лезть.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, скорее даже вообще не нужно

Comment: [fixed Statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо за указание на бесполезный код, заменил на цикл. И страница с msdn`а помогла, всё работает.

Comment: Опубликуйте ответ. Всем будет полезно. / А может мы ещё ошибки найдём.